# DLL in GAC --- When the updated DLL in GAC will take effect

Tags: c#, .net, dll, gac

We have 2 projects  - one for a DLL and one for a GUI program which refers to the DLL file.

Now the DLL file has been deployed into GAC. And when we run the GUI program, we found there is an issue. As I checked the source code, the issue is with the DLL. Then I open the project for the DLL and do some modification. And then build the DLL file and re-deploy it into GAC (by gacutil command).

Now my question is: will the updated DLL take effect immediately? As the GUI program is still running when I did the steps above, do I have to restart the GUI program to see if the issue has been fixed or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to stop and rebuild the program. Rebuilding it and setting copylocal on the dll to true will ensure that your GUI program has the updated version of the dll.

Once having done this restart the program and see if it has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. The dll has been deployed into GAC. It's not in the same folder of GUI program.